# Unable to delete information from my firebase

Tags: firebase

I was testing some changes to my firebase and accidently submitted 100's of updates to a reference. Now when I try and delete the reference it then creates a new reference with different data.

I have tried deleting everything in the firebase but it will just keep creating a new reference.

In this specific example I used set() to add 5 random values to a user name Michael. The 5 random values were called 100's of times and now when I delete the Michael user to test again it already has a value queued up and recreates itself immediately. I looked at my upload usage and it showed a huge amount of data being uploaded at one point that coincides with this error.

Any idea how to remove these queued up changes?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to disconnect the client that is writing this data. I suspect somewhere you have a process running that is generating these writes.

If you can't stop the offending process for some reason, you could always modify your security rules to deny access to the client that's doing the writes (or if it's a server using a Firebase Secret to authenticate, you could revoke its secret).

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue - think it has to do with your session / caching.

Try logging out of firebase and back in - if the records are still there, make a backup of your security rules, then use:

```
{
  "rules": {
      ".read": false,
      ".write": false
  }
}
```

and delete them.